# Интеграция Битрикса в 1С

Tags: битрикс, 1с

имеется настроенный Битрикс сайт с базой товаров.
Возможно ли все эти товары импортировать в 1С (при помощи модуля интеграции) ? Важно повторить все свойства товара как они созданы на сайте + highload блоки. Или нужно создавать номенклатуру в 1С с такими же полями как на сайте, и только потом загружать из Битрикса. 
Никогда не работал с 1С но работаю с битриксом. Большинство найденных мной инструкций направлены на обратную связь (1С -> Битрикс). Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нет создавать ничего не нужно. Согласно документациям и статьям от 1С-Битрикс это происходит в автоматическом режиме. [Вот](https://1c.1c-bitrix.ru/blog/blog1c/catalog_import.php) краткая инструкция как это работает. Немного устарела часть в плане настройки модуля обмена на стороне 1С, но общий принцип остался прежним.

Comment: Всё не так просто, данную инструкцию я находил, товары импортируются, но даже Вес (стандартное в битриксе поле) из Торгового каталога Битрикс не подхватывается, я уже не говорю о созданных мною полях и связей этих полей с hload инфоблоками. Импортируются картинки, название, иногда описание. Может я смотрю не там (никогда прежде не открывал 1С), мне нужно только настроить чтобы всё верно передавалось в обе стороны и отдать это заказчику. Пока я не вижу правильного импорта увы (или смотрю не там). Обратная связь (1С -> Битрикс) выглядит логично, но вот сайт у нас давно, а 1С приобрели вчера.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как логика хранения данных разная у сайта и 1С. В своем опыте только выгружал из базы на сайт. В обратную сторону коллеги пробовали, но с их рассказов работает "криво". 
Лично мой опыт в работе с интеграцией 1С-Битрикс показал, что модуль "сыроват". Хоть и утверждают, что интеграция настраивается в два щелчка и на "ура!".
По сути дополнительные поля из Битрикса в 1С являются характеристиками и доп.свойствами.
Может быть выключен данный функционал в базе и поэтому не все прогружает.